# MongoDB Remote Connections

Tags: php, mongodb

I installed MongoDB the last version 
and i want to connect to MongoDB with an other server with this test code.
- installed MongoDB Driver in PHP Server
- Allowed PHP Server IP in MongoDB iptabels:

PHP Code:

```html
    <?php
$m = new MongoClient("mongodb://X.X.X.X:27017");
$dbname = $m->selectDB("Test");
$collection = $dbname->selectCollection("Shows"); 
$data1 = array(
        'user_id' => 'salam',
        'age' => 20,
        'Status' => 'Allll'
        );
$dbname = $collection->insert($data1, array('$data1' => 1));  
$results = $collection->find();
echo "<pre>";
foreach($results as $test) {
    print_r($test);
} 
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

ERROR:

> atal error: Uncaught exception 'MongoConnectionException' with message 'Failed to connect to: X.X.X.X.X.X:27017: Connection timed out' in /home/payam48/domains/.../public_html/includes/classes/class.mongodatabase.php:9 Stack trace: #0 /home/payam48/domains/.../public_html/includes/classes/class.mongodatabase.php(9): MongoClient->__construct('mongodb://178.1...') #1 /home/payam48/domains/.../public_html/includes/classes/class.doctor.php(519): Mongodatabase->__construct('1c5b98782e44ccd...', 'b2f202952b685b6...') #2 /home/payam48/domains/.../public_html/includes/classes/class.doctor.php(486): Doctor->online_delete() #3 /home/payam48/domains/.../public_html/application/controllers/managedoctor.php(27): Doctor->delete('4') #4 /home/payam48/domains/.../public_html/application/core/router.class.php(118): managedoctorController->delete() #5 /home/payam48/domains/.../public_html/index.php(9): router-> in /home/payam48/domains/.../public_html/includes/classes/class.mongodatabase.php on line 9

Comment: What are your `bindIp` settings? Can you connect to the mongo on a shell? You don't seem to utilize authorization in your script.

Comment: yes i can connect to mongo on shell.